# I am studying Oracle, But We are Asked how to Select data from multiple tables without using JOIN clause

Tags: oracle

For Instance

Suppose You have multiple tables Like these!

**Students(StudId, Sname, SRegNo),

Lecturers(LectId, LectName, Lect Course),

Courses(CourseId, CourseName, Coursemarks)**

*How can you Join them by Getting only, Sname, Lectname and CourseMarks*

Comment: Tha question is not very precise so you can get only vague answer. To *select data from multiple tables without using JOIN clause* use a) the former Oracle join syntax, b) use UNION

Comment: What kind of silly requirement is this? If "join" is the best method for a job, the school shouldn't teach you how to do the same job in an inferior way. What's the purpose? I would stay away from such courses, if I had a choice.